# How to create vertical marker lines at specific x-axis values on a stacked area chart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to create vertical lines as specific dates to mark "events".  My data looks like this:

[image]

I would like my chart to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This solves the issue:*

**:Caveat:**

*Combo Chart is the best option for the issue, readers may suggest another one.*

---

[image]

**How it works:**

- First select B19:D29 & draw Staked Area Chart.
- Create one Helper Column like I've in Column F & used formula is:

  `=IF(ISBLANK(E20),0,100)`
- This formula gets Numeric value `100` for every **Yes**, since Graph
  only uses *Numeric data*, and `100` is editable, for tallest & proper
  visibility `100` has been used.
- Now Copy F19:F29, select Graph then use Paste.
- Select Graph, Right click then select Change Chart Type.
- Under the Chart category now select type is COMBO, for *Helper Column*
  select *Clustered Column*.
- Finally select Clustered Column Bar & Right Click, then hit Format
  Data Series, and set at Gap Width at maximum ( is 500 ), will make
  bar thinnest, *you may set Gap Width as needed.*

---

**N.B.**

- You may use as many data columns.
- For proper Visualization I've used small Data Set.
- You may hide the Helper Column.

Comment: Glad to help you @marathon ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions similar to what @Rajesh posted.

First suggestion, add a line chart series, then add drop lines.

Chart 1 shows the original area chart.

In column F, insert the value at the top of the lines (e.g., 25) for each date where you want a line.

Copy the data in column F, select the chart, and paste. This adds a new stacked area with a peak where the lines will go (Chart 2).

Right click on this new series, choose Change Series Chart Type. In the dialog, select a line chart type for this series, and click OK (Chart 3).

In chart 4:

- Select the new series, on the Chart Design tab of the ribbon, click
  Add Chart Element > Lines > Drop Lines. Format the drop lines to make
  them a bit thicker and darker.
- Format the new series to show no lines
  and no markers.
- Change the Y axis maximum.

[image]

Second suggestion, add a line chart series, then add error bars.

Chart 1 shows the original area chart.

In column F, insert a zero at the top of the lines for each date where you want a line.

Copy the data in column F, select the chart, and paste. This adds a new stacked area with a peak where the lines will go (Chart 2). You can't see this series, because it has a height of zero.

Right click on any series, choose Change Series Chart Type. In the dialog, select a line chart type for the added series, and click OK (Chart 3).

Right click the chart, choose Select Data. Click the Hidden and Empty Cells button, and choose to show empty cells as gaps (Chart 4).

Select the new series with markers, click the plus icon next to the chart, select Error Bars > More Options (Chart 5).

In Chart 6:

- Format the error bars to show Plus direction, No Caps, length of 25, and thicken the line.
- Format the series to show no line and no markers.
- Change the Y axis maximum to 25.

[image]